# To config Git Bash used within WSL

Tags: git, config, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-bash

Using Windows Git Bash within WSL has no problem at all, except that all my existing git aliases stop working. How to make `git` tell/report where it reads its config from?

Within WSL:

```
$ type git.exe
git.exe is hashed (/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe)
```

So where does such git reads its config from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

and (at least if you're on wsl2, which as I understand it isn't really a windows subsystem at all, it's a hypervisor hosting windows and linux as siblings),

```
strace -fefile git config -l
```

will show you every system call the command issues that supplies a file path.

Answer (score -1):

What I suggest is you run in wsl:

```
sudo ln -fs '/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe' /usr/bin/git
```

so that your git aliases should continue working, and you can just run `git commit ...`

Windows git always read config from Windows %USERPROFILE% which is usually C:\Users\your-name, even launched from WSL.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  `/usr/bin` is managed by the package manager and you'll cause problems if you do this and some Linux program tries to install Git.  Better to symlink it into something like `~/bin`, assuming that's in your `PATH`.

Comment: @bk2204 some Linux program ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: If you install a package in your Linux environment that depends on or recommends the `git` package, such as the Debian packages for repo or Docker, that will result in trying to install the `git` package, which will likely fail if you've done this, or at least it will break the behavior you were relying on.  `/usr/bin` should only be modified via the package manager, never by hand.

Comment: Do you mean installing Docker will install git ?

Comment: By default in Debian, yes.

Comment: Have you ever tried to install Docker on Debian@WSL ?

Comment: I'm not as concerned about package management, since someone could always came along in any distro and install a newer version from source (without going through the distro's packaging management).  But I kind of cringe at the idea of linking a Windows executable (even MinGW-based) into the Linux `/usr/bin`.  Preferable to keep Windows executables in their own directories (or with other Windows executables) and edit the path to include them., as @bk2204 says, imho.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Even if you include Windows directories in the path, you still need to invoke it as `git.exe`, is this what you wanted ? are you going to create aliases ?